# c++ : segmentation fault in breadth first search in graph class

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, graph, graph-algorithm

I am a bit experienced in c++ and tried to implement a graph class with nodes which are numbered from 1 to n (and every edge is weighted with 6) with a method to find all reachable nodes from a given one by breadth depth first. However, in some testcases I get a segmentation fault and don't know why. The error seems to happen when i push the next node to visit into the queue - if I comment out this line, the program works.
I used heap storage to avoid any problems with any empty pointers, still I get this kind of fault.
I would be thankful for any help.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
std::vector<node*> connections;
int number;

node(int x){
    number = x;
}

void connect(node *B){
    connections.push_back(B);
}

bool hasConnectionTo(int y){
    for(node *n : connections){
        if(n->number == y){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
};

class graph{
public:
std::vector<node> nodes;

bool nodeExists(int x){
    for(node n : nodes){
        if(n.number == x){
            return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}

node* find(int x){
    node *returnNode;
    if(nodeExists(x)){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < this->nodes.size() ; i++){
            if(this->nodes[i].number == x){
                returnNode = &this->nodes[i];
                return returnNode;
            }
        }
    }    
    return NULL;
}    

void addEdge(int x, int y){     //adds a connection between node1 and node2
    if(this->nodeExists(x) && this->nodeExists(y)){
        node *nodex = this->find(x);
        node *nodey = this->find(y);
        if(!nodex->hasConnectionTo(y)){
            nodex->connect(nodey);
            nodey->connect(nodex);
        }
    }else if(this->nodeExists(x) && !this->nodeExists(y)){
        node *nodex = this->find(x);
        node *nodey = new node(y);
        nodex->connect(nodey);
        nodey->connect(nodex);
        this->nodes.push_back(*nodey);
    }else if(this->nodeExists(y) && !this->nodeExists(x)){
        node *nodey = this->find(y);
        node *nodex = new node(x);
        nodey->connect(nodex);
        nodex->connect(nodey);
        this->nodes.push_back(*nodex);
    }else{
        node *nodex = new node(x);
        node *nodey = new node(y);
        nodex->connect(nodey);
        nodey->connect(nodex);
        this->nodes.push_back(*nodex);
        this->nodes.push_back(*nodey);
    }
}

void breadthFirstLookup(int root, int numberOfNodes){
    std::queue<node*> q;
    int distances[numberOfNodes];    //store the distance to node n in distances[n-1]
    bool visited[numberOfNodes];
    for(int j = 0 ; j < numberOfNodes ; j++){
        distances[j] = 0;
        visited[j] = false;
    }
    if (this->nodeExists(root)){
        node *start = new node(1);
        start = this->find(root);
        node *tmp = new node(1);
        q.push(start);
        while(!q.empty()){
            tmp = this->find(q.front()->number);
            visited[tmp->number-1] = true;
            q.pop();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < tmp->connections.size() ; i++){
                if(!visited[tmp->connections[i]->number-1]){
                    distances[tmp->connections[i]->number-1] = distances[tmp->number-1] + 6;
                    q.push(tmp->connections[i]);    //<--this is where the error happens
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0 ; k < numberOfNodes ; k++){    //print distance to all nodes except the root node, -1 if no connections exists
        if(k+1 != root){
            if(distances[k] != 0){
                cout << distances[k] <<" ";
            } else{
                cout << -1 <<" ";
            }
        }
    }
    cout <<"\n";
}
};
```

Comment: I am familiar with breadth-first search and depth-first search. What is "breadth depth first"?

Comment: Also, what is the simplest test case that produces the error?

Comment: The simplest test case that produces the error is a graph with 4 nodes and 2 edges: Node 1 is linked to node 2 and node 3 and I want to get all connections from node 1.

Comment: Did you run your code in a debugger to find out which line the problem occurs on? I bet it's *not* the q->push line, but commenting out that line makes it not crash because it makes the algorithm not work properly.

Comment: How do you have an unconnected node (`4`) if your `graph` has no method to add a node without an edge?

Comment: If the method can't find a node with a certain number it prints "-1" . That's the reason I have the number of nodes as an input variable.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your nodes have pointers to each other, but you store nodes in a vector. A vector has the right to move its elements around in ways that can invalidate old pointers. And even if the vector never moved any of its elements, you have code like this:

```
else if(this->nodeExists(x) && !this->nodeExists(y)){
  node *nodex = this->find(x);
  node *nodey = new node(y);
  nodex->connect(nodey);
  nodey->connect(nodex);
  this->nodes.push_back(*nodey);
}
```

After `nodex->connect(nodey);`, node x contains the pointer `nodey`. But after `nodes.push_back(*nodey);` (the `this->` is superfluous), the vector `nodes` contains *a copy of the node that `nodey` points to.* So `nodey` -- which is the pointer stored in node x -- points to a node which still exists, but is not in the vector.

The specific way in which this code causes a segfault depends on code you haven't shown us, but this handling of pointers is the fundamental cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, is there any way to store nodes in a way that they really contain pointers to the other nodes? Is that even desirable (I thought it would be a good practice for pointers) ?

Comment: @AlexConfused: Yes, `graph` could maintain a collection of *pointers*, rather than a collection of nodes. Or you could use a container other than `vector`, one that would not invalidate pointers, and handle it very carefully. (If by "good practice" you mean the correct way to use pointers, it's perfectly all right-- if you mean educational exercise, this sure is!)